# Skip yAxis gridLines if there is no data in them

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a simple chart where xAxis is the date the user selected an attribute while yAxis is the attribute the user selected.

Each attribute corresponds to a value starting from 0. So for example, attribute0 has a value of 0 and so on.

What i would like to do is to not display yAxis grid lines for attributes that were not selected by the user.[image: Sample picture]

As can be seen in the screenshot the user has selected attributes 3,4,5 and 9. The problem is that i don't want to show yAxis grid lines for the rest of the attributes(1,2,6,7 and 8) while preserving the value of the displayed attributes. This means that i want attribute 9 to have a value of 9 even if it is displayed in line 4 in this example(assuming that there is a way to skip empty gridLines)

The end result i would like to be like this for this example.[image: End result]

If the user selects a new attribute the next day, one that does not already exists in the graph, this attribute should be added in the same way.

Any ideas?

I hope i am explaining my self correctly.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using `categories` on the y axis.

Your y values then need to be the category index of the selected value, rather than the value itself.

So, in your example, you would have:

```
categories = ['3','4','5','9']
```

And the y values for that would be 0,1,2,3 instead of 3,4,5,9.

Something like (random x value used):

```
data: [[100,0],[100,1],[100,2],[100,3]]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3d3fuhbb/62/